# replacement of lambda expression in java 1.7

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-7

```
 timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> sendTimeToAll(session),0,1,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

This expression is used in java 8, how to write this in java 7 version

Comment: That depends on the arguments the `scheduleAtFixedRate` method expects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like a `Runnable`, so you can implement it as a anonymous inner class.

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            sendTimeToAll(session);
        }
    }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 2):

The lambda `() -> sendTimeToAll(session)` is nothing more than a direct implementation of the `Runnable`-interface.

So `() -> sendTimeToAll(session)` is equivalent to this

```
new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        sendTimeToAll(session);
    }
}
```